# Youtube embedded videos that all include rel=0 are now showing related videos :-(

Tags: video, iframe, youtube

please help.

For some reason dozens of my embedded videos which used to NOT show related videos at end, now seem to be ignoring rel=0 in url because related videos display at end :-(

e.g. this is the code which has worked fine for ages, but now it shows related videos at end:

```
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lM2cAv8jvWw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

View source here:
https://blog.thorlaser.com/novothor-testimonial-bethany-marinac/

It's the same on several websites, some Wordpress and others just static html/php sites.

```
<iframe width="500" height="281" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VzMJUxalkFo?rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

View source here:
https://www.thorlaser.com/LLLT/how-does-LLLT-work.htm

If you go to the end of video, you will see it showing related videos, but it's not meant to.
Lots here and all showing related videos at end:
https://www.thorlaser.com/video/

Any idea how I could get this working again?
Any one have some solutions I can try?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted :-)

I was testing in my default Google Chrome browser, so I then checked in Safari and videos work correctly :-)

So I then tested in Google Chrome (Incognito Mode) and they are also correct.

So I believe it's just a setting in my own Chrome causing the issue so I will see if it's some plugin/addon conflict.